# Form in html doesn't show text after select box

Tags: html, select

I have this form in html http://jsfiddle.net/TzHrM/ but text after a select box for selecting gender, is not shown.

Also, here you have the code:

```
<form action="">
            First name: <input type="text" id="firstname" name="FirstName" value=""><br>
            Midname: <input type="text" id="midname" name="MidName" value=""><br>
            Last name: <input type="text" id="lastname" name="LastName" value=""><br>
            NIF: <input type="text" id="nif" name="NIF" value=""><br>
            Age: <input type="text" id="age" name="Age" value=""><br>
            Gender: <select id="gender"><option value="hombre">Hombre</option><option value="mujer">Mujer</option><br>
            <br>Phone number: <input type="text" id="phone" name="Phone" value=""><br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" id="mail" name="Mail" value=""><br>
            City: <input type="text" id="city" name="City" value=""><br>
    </form>
```

I tried with many 
 but same result.

Comment: You are missing [label elements](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text isn't *after* the select, it is **inside** it. You forgot the end tag: `</select>`

This should have been picked up by [basic automated QA](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have missed closing of select tag. Just close select tag and it will show

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you